# Updating the status in UI methods from a non-UI thread

Tags: java, android

I have an `Activity` that includes a `TextView` to display the current status of the app.  Besides `MainActivity` there is another class that is used for checking for updates and then updating the app if appropriate.

This is the important part of the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView status;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        status  = findViewById(R.id.status);

        new Update().check();
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status.setText(status);
    }
}
```

How can I update the status `TextView` from within the `Update` class?

```
    public class Update extends Activity {
        public void check(final Context c) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    TextView status = findViewById(R.id.status);
                    status.setText("Checking for updates...");
                }
            });

            // final TextView status = getApplicationContext().findViewById(R.id.status);
            //  status.setText("Checking for updates");

            // Check for updates...

        }

        public class UpdateApp extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {
            private Context context;
            public void setContext(Context contextf){
                context = contextf;
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            // Update the app

            }
        }
    }
```

Attempting to run `getApplicationContext().findViewById(R.id.status)` crashes the app.  When I put it in a `try` block it **still** crashes the app - how can that be when I `catch` a `Throwable` object? ... that doesn't make sense!!!

Using `runOnUiThread` the app runs but the status is not updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `UpdateApp` AsynTask in new file.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView status;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        status  = findViewById(R.id.status);

        new UpdateApp(status).execute();
    }
}
```

**UpdateApp.java**

```
public class UpdateApp extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {
    private TextView status;
    public UpdateApp(TextView status){
        this.status = status;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        status.setText("Update complete");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
         status.setText("Checking for updates...");
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        // Update the app

    }
}
```

Comment: The reason for putting the update code in a separate class was to make the code reusable for different apps in the future.

Comment: then put the async task in a new file. Let me update

Comment: and have memory leak after rotation

Comment: The current code that checks updates displays an `AlertDialog` to give the user the option to install the update or not.  Will the `onPreExecute()` method have access to the UI to be able to display this option?

Comment: Thank you @IgorBykov for pointing out the memory leak.  I **think** I can see what causes it but will ask another question about it to check my understanding and that I am able to avoid it.

Comment: @İanBoddison at least you need to put TextView in weakreference. This will avoid the memory leak. Also, you need to cancel AsyncTask on destroy method

Answer (score 0):

You just don't need another class to make it works, just copy your `UpdateApp` class inside MainActivity to access your `status` view.

In case you want your `UpdateApp` class to be in a different file (witch I recommend, to separate classes responsibility) you'd need a callback: a reference to your activity to update the `status` view from the `AsyncTask` class. The way you can make it is using `Interfaces`. Take a look to this example

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CallbackInterface {

    private TextView status;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        status  = findViewById(R.id.status);
        new LoaderClass(this).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void setStatusText(String text) {
        status.setText(text);
    }
}
```

CallbackInterface.java

```
public interface CallbackInterface {
    void setStatusText(String text);
}
```

LoaderClass.java

```
public class LoaderClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private CallbackInterface callbackInterface;

    public LoaderClass(CallbackInterface callback) {
        callbackInterface = callback;
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        callbackInterface.setStatusText("Loaded text");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I right that the `interface` is a separate file just as a `class` is a separate file?

Comment: Yes! I've attached before the code the name of the files. There are 3 files: MainActivity, CallbackInterface (the interface) and LoaderClass (the AsyncTask class)

Answer (score 0):

If you are in any Activity you can use runonUIthread() like -

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run () {

          // do your magic here

        }
    });
```

Comment: runOnMainThread()  is included in the original code but doesn't update the UI